# Identifying a Specific Table Hierarchy... Don't Know Where to Start

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I am trying to identify/mark records where an entry exists in a specific column. While that may be pretty straightforward using a loop, I must also mark those records representing the "Parent" records. This is where I'm stuck.

**Here is my starting data...**

[image: StartingData]

**Here is what I know so far**... The data includes a list of different database tables. This Excel file is then imported into Lucidchart to create a table hierarchy diagram.

Only tables with an entry in the **Tag** column and their respective Parent Tables should be included in the load. This is accomplished by marking the **Include** column as "Yes" to filter the import for only the entries where Include = "Yes."

**Pseudo-Code:**

1. Loop through each row and identify which ones have a value in the **Tag** column (the value does not matter).
2. If the **Tag** column is populated, update the corresponding **Include** column with a "Yes" value. *Example: The Software table has a Tag value of "Tag A." Therefore, update the corresponding Include column = "Yes"*
3. For each row that has a value in the **Tag** column, find its **Parent Table** and update the Parent Table row so that its **Include** column = "Yes."
4. Continue updating the Parent Table rows until the Base table is reached (top of the table hierarchy). *Example: The Windows Server table has a Tag entry. Therefore, update the corresponding Include column = "Yes" for the Windows Server, Server, Computer, Hardware, and Base tables*

**Here is the desired end state...**

[image: EndState]

I think I need to do something with one or more arrays, but I'm having trouble figuring it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: should be possible with `LAMBDA`. I think the pseudo-code should be something like 1. identify full hierarchy for rows with tag (putting that into an array). 2. if row value is in that array then include cell equals yes, else no. Good luck.

Comment: step 1 will require the recursive ability of `LAMBDA`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have never used the LAMBDA function before, so this should be a good introduction for me.